# How to plot time series plots of different products together at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that has 988 different product values over time as follows:

**Note:** This is just for one product (`ContextID` is product number)

```
p1 = unique_df[unique_df['ContextID'] == 7289972]
ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu = 0.07, kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'scale')
p1['y_ocsvm1'] = ocsvm.fit_predict(p1.values[:,[1]])
```

This gave the following dataframe:

```
    ContextID   BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID  Time_Elapsed    y_ocsvm1
104083  7289972 1.953125    1   0.0 1
104084  7289972 1.953125    1   0.055   1
104085  7289972 2.05078125  2   0.156   1
104086  7289972 2.05078125  2   0.48700000000000004 1
104087  7289972 2.05078125  2   1.477   1
104088  7289972 1.953125    2   2.4770000000000003  1
104089  7289972 1.7578125   2   3.4770000000000003  1
104090  7289972 1.7578125   2   4.487   1
104091  7289972 1.85546875  2   5.993   1
104092  7289972 1.7578125   2   6.545000000000001   1
104093  7289972 9.08203125  5   7.9830000000000005  1
104094  7289972 46.19140625 5   8.993   1
104095  7289972 46.19140625 5   9.993   1
104096  7289972 46.19140625 5   11.393  1
104097  7289972 46.19140625 5   11.993  1
104098  7289972 46.6796875  5   13.093  1
104099  7289972 46.6796875  5   13.384  1
104100  7289972 46.6796875  5   14.388000000000002  1
104101  7289972 46.6796875  5   15.386000000000001  1
104102  7289972 46.6796875  5   16.386000000000003  1
104103  7289972 46.6796875  5   17.396  1
104104  7289972 46.6796875  5   18.406000000000002  1
104105  7289972 46.6796875  5   19.396  1
104106  7289972 46.6796875  5   20.396  1
104107  7289972 46.6796875  5   21.396  1
104108  7289972 46.6796875  7   22.386000000000003  1
104109  7289972 46.6796875  7   23.456000000000003  1
104110  7289972 46.6796875  7   24.404  1
104111  7289972 46.6796875  12  25.443  1
104112  7289972 46.6796875  12  26.443  1
104113  7289972 46.6796875  12  27.443  1
104114  7289972 46.6796875  12  28.453000000000003  1
104115  7289972 46.6796875  12  29.443  1
104116  7289972 46.6796875  12  30.443  1
104117  7289972 46.6796875  12  31.443  1
104118  7289972 46.6796875  15  32.472  1
104119  7289972 46.6796875  15  33.444  1
104120  7289972 46.6796875  16  34.443000000000005  1
104121  7289972 46.6796875  16  35.443000000000005  1
104122  7289972 46.6796875  17  36.443000000000005  1
104123  7289972 25.09765625 19  37.503  -1
104124  7289972 45.99609375 19  38.513000000000005  -1
104125  7289972 59.08203125 19  39.503  1
104126  7289972 61.81640625 19  40.503  1
104127  7289972 62.59765625 19  41.503  1
104128  7289972 63.671875   19  42.503  1
104129  7289972 65.625  19  43.503  1
104130  7289972 66.69921875 19  44.503  1
104131  7289972 67.3828125  19  45.532000000000004  1
104132  7289972 67.3828125  19  46.502  1
104133  7289972 67.67578125 19  47.501000000000005  1
104134  7289972 68.26171875 19  48.501000000000005  1
104135  7289972 69.04296875 19  49.501000000000005  1
104136  7289972 69.82421875 19  50.501000000000005  1
104137  7289972 69.82421875 19  51.501000000000005  1
104138  7289972 70.8984375  19  52.501000000000005  1
104139  7289972 70.8984375  19  53.502  1
104140  7289972 70.8984375  19  54.502  1
104141  7289972 70.8984375  19  55.502  1
104142  7289972 71.6796875  19  56.502  1
104143  7289972 71.6796875  19  57.50000000000001   1
104144  7289972 72.55859375 19  58.923  1
104145  7289972 72.55859375 19  59.541000000000004  1
104146  7289972 72.55859375 19  60.541000000000004  1
104147  7289972 72.55859375 19  61.540000000000006  1
104148  7289972 72.55859375 19  62.540000000000006  1
104149  7289972 72.55859375 19  63.540000000000006  1
104150  7289972 73.33984375 19  64.54   1
104151  7289972 73.33984375 19  65.539  1
104152  7289972 73.33984375 19  66.539  1
104153  7289972 74.12109375 19  67.539  1
104154  7289972 74.12109375 19  68.539  1
104155  7289972 74.12109375 19  69.54   1
104156  7289972 73.2421875  19  70.54   1
104157  7289972 73.2421875  19  71.54   1
104158  7289972 74.0234375  19  73.02300000000001   1
104159  7289972 74.0234375  19  73.55000000000001   1
104160  7289972 74.0234375  19  75.153  1
104161  7289972 74.0234375  19  75.693  1
104162  7289972 74.0234375  19  76.953  1
104163  7289972 74.0234375  19  78.093  1
104164  7289972 74.0234375  19  78.693  1
104165  7289972 74.0234375  19  80.05300000000001   1
104166  7289972 74.0234375  19  80.703  1
104167  7289972 74.90234375 19  81.703  1
104168  7289972 74.90234375 19  82.953  1
104169  7289972 74.12109375 19  83.69300000000001   1
104170  7289972 74.12109375 19  84.69300000000001   1
104171  7289972 74.12109375 19  85.69300000000001   1
104172  7289972 74.12109375 19  86.69300000000001   1
104173  7289972 74.12109375 19  88.10300000000001   1
104174  7289972 75.0    19  88.69300000000001   -1
104175  7289972 75.0    19  89.953  -1
104176  7289972 75.0    19  90.953  -1
104177  7289972 74.21875    19  91.953  1
104178  7289972 74.21875    19  92.953  1
104179  7289972 74.21875    19  93.69300000000001   1
104180  7289972 75.0    19  94.69300000000001   -1
104181  7289972 75.0    19  95.953  -1
104182  7289972 75.0    19  96.69300000000001   -1
104183  7289972 75.0    19  97.69300000000001   -1
104184  7289972 74.12109375 19  98.953  1
104185  7289972 74.12109375 19  99.653  1
104186  7289972 74.12109375 19  100.543 1
104187  7289972 74.90234375 19  101.85300000000001  1
104188  7289972 6.4453125   24  102.545 1
104189  7289972 3.515625    24  104.13300000000001  1
104190  7289972 2.5390625   24  104.983 1
104191  7289972 2.05078125  24  105.873 1
104192  7289972 2.05078125  24  106.97300000000001  1
104193  7289972 2.05078125  24  107.665 1
104194  7289972 1.953125    24  108.70500000000001  1
104195  7289972 1.953125    24  108.786 1
104196  7289972 1.953125    24  109.253 1
104197  7289972 1.953125    24  110.17500000000001  1
104198  7289972 2.05078125  24  111.165 1
104199  7289972 1.85546875  24  112.16300000000001  1
104200  7289972 1.85546875  24  113.165 1
104201  7289972 1.85546875  24  114.165 1
104202  7289972 1.85546875  24  115.165 1
104203  7289972 1.85546875  24  116.165 1
104204  7289972 2.05078125  24  117.23500000000001  1
104205  7289972 1.953125    24  118.185 1
104206  7289972 1.953125    24  119.185 1
104207  7289972 1.7578125   24  120.185 1
104208  7289972 1.66015625  24  121.185 -1
104209  7289972 1.7578125   24  122.185 1
104210  7289972 1.7578125   24  123.185 1
104211  7289972 1.7578125   24  124.185 1
104212  7289972 1.85546875  24  125.185 1
104213  7289972 1.85546875  24  126.185 1
104214  7289972 1.953125    24  127.224 1
104215  7289972 1.953125    24  127.41000000000001  1
104216  7289972 1.953125    24  128.073 1
104217  7289972 1.953125    24  128.672 1
104218  7289972 1.953125    24  129.692 1
104219  7289972 1.7578125   24  130.74200000000002  1
104220  7289972 1.85546875  24  131.782 1
104221  7289972 1.85546875  24  132.83200000000002  1
104222  7289972 1.85546875  24  133.852 1
104223  7289972 1.7578125   24  134.882 1
104224  7289972 1.85546875  24  135.9   1
104225  7289972 1.85546875  24  136.92000000000002  1
104226  7289972 1.7578125   24  137.93200000000002  1
104227  7289972 1.7578125   25  138.45100000000002  1
104228  7289972 1.85546875  25  139.481 1
104229  7289972 1.85546875  25  140.501 1
104230  7289972 1.85546875  26  141.531 1
104231  7289972 1.7578125   26  142.55100000000002  1
104232  7289972 1.953125    26  143.833 1
104233  7289972 1.953125    26  144.681 1
104234  7289972 1.85546875  26  145.741 1
104235  7289972 1.85546875  27  146.77  1
104236  7289972 1.85546875  27  147.79000000000002  1
104237  7289972 1.85546875  27  148.82000000000002  1
104238  7289972 1.953125    27  149.84  1
104239  7289972 1.85546875  27  150.86  1
104240  7289972 1.953125    27  151.92000000000002  1
104241  7289972 1.85546875  27  152.958 1
104242  7289972 1.7578125   27  153.978 1
104243  7289972 1.85546875  27  155.008 1
104244  7289972 1.85546875  27  156.02800000000002  1
104245  7289972 1.7578125   27  157.048 1
104246  7289972 1.85546875  27  158.12800000000001  1
```

after that, I plotted the `Time_Elapsed` vs `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` curve as follows:

```
x_axis = p1.values[:,3]
y_axis = p1.values[:,1]

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.scatter(p1.values[p1['y_ocsvm1'] == 1, 3], p1.values[p1['y_ocsvm1'] == 1, 1], c = 'green', label = 'Normal')
plt.scatter(p1.values[p1['y_ocsvm1'] == -1, 3], p1.values[p1['y_ocsvm1'] == -1, 1], c = 'red', label = 'Outlier')
```

which gives me a plot as follows:

[image]

I would like help in the following tasks:

1. My dataframe has 988 different `ContextID`s (products) as above. I would like to know how can I plot, say first 200 products together so that all the plots overlap each other and are shown in one window, then the next 200 products overlap each other and are shown in the second window and so on. So, in the end, I'll have 5 different windows, 4 of which will have overlapping plots of 200 different products and the 5th window will have overlapping plots of 188 different products.
2. If possible, can the above task be achieved using `plotly` to ensure interactivity, meaning when I hover on one plot, it gets highlighted separately? If not, then `matplotlib` or `seaborn` are absolutely fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using itertools `grouper` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

We'll use this to group the data per 200

Then we need a method to add a group of data to an axis `ax`

```
def add_to_axes(ax, data, context_id=None):
    data.plot(
        x="Time_Elapsed",
        y="BacksGas_Flow_sccm",
        label=context_id,
        # color="blue",
        ax=ax,
    )
    outlier = data["y_ocsvm1"] == -1
    data[~outlier].plot.scatter(
        x="Time_Elapsed",
        y="BacksGas_Flow_sccm",
        color="green",
        label="Normal",
        ax=ax,
    )
    data[outlier].plot.scatter(
        x="Time_Elapsed",
        y="BacksGas_Flow_sccm",
        color="red",
        label="outlier",
        ax=ax,
    )
```

and a method to group the data in subgroups, make a new figure for each subgroup and add the  different `context_id`s to a plot.

```
def group_plots(df, group_size=200):
    for group in grouper(df.groupby("ContextID"), n=group_size):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        # group = list(filter(None, group))
        # print(group)
        for context_id, data in filter(None, group):
            # print(context_id, data.head())
            add_to_axes(ax, data, context_id)
        yield fig
```

This can be called like this to produce the plots:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = Path("data/test2.csv")
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter="\s+", decimal=",") # my dummy data

    for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(data)):
        fig.savefig(f"data/output{i}.png") # or do whathever you need with the fig
```

I don't know `plot.ly`, so this might be done with that too. The main components stay the same:

a method to group the data, a method that makes a new figure per data subgroup, and a method that adds 1 series to an existing plot

Comment: Hey @Maarten, firstly thank you for your response. I tried your code, but it just opens one window containing the first 200 products and doesn't plot others. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: Hey, I did `from pylab import show` and in place of `fig.savefig`, I did `show()` and it opens 5 windows containing all the products graphs

Comment: I have accepted your answer since it was correct :)